# IIS Rewrite module doesn't redirect on first load of the page

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I use IIS 6.2 to host a website and I've set up the rewrite module to automatically redirect HTTP requests to HTTPs.
Using a brownser on incognito mode, when I request for the http:// version it doesn't redirect to the HTTPs version.
Then, when I reload the page I correctly get the HTTPs version.

I've tried both with appendQueryString true and false.

Here is my web.config rewrite part:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I expect that every request will be served as HTTPs.
I would not want to see "Not secure" on the browser tab.

Comment: which operating system and certificate are you using?

Comment: It's a Windows 2012 R2 server with an OV wildcard ssl cerificate

Comment: please check your rule.i think this is not enabled. used this  <rule name="Force SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="(.*)" /><conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" /> </conditions><action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" /></rule> also enable append querysting other wise this rule will not add query string value in url. in which browser you get this "not secure"?

Comment: Ops... I feel quite stupid at this point. I focused on the rule and forgot the very basics. Thank you very much and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: seems your issue is resolved. I posted as answer please mark the post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your rule.i think this is not enabled.
 use below rule:

```
<rule name="Force SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 
   <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" /> 
      </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>`
```

also, enable append query string otherwise this rule will not add query string value in url.

Regards,
Jalpa